# Help! Rotation formulas

Tags: calculus

$3x^2-10xy+3y^2-32=0$. Write the appropriate rotation formulas so that in a rotated system the equation has no $x'y'$ term. I used the $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Ey+F=0$. Using the formula $\tan$ or $\cot(2\theta) = (A-C)/B$ but I got stuck since $A = C$ so it makes zero I got stuck  please help.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is OK till here but we can proceed further after $\cot(2\theta) = (A-C)/B $

So next:  $ \tan 2 \theta = \infty $, its $ \tan^{-1}$ value is $\pi/2$.

Half angle is $\pi/4$, it is an ellipse whose major axis is inclined at $\pi/4$ to the x-axis.

Comment: Why infinity? Thank you so much for answering